# make a pipeline in queue when one is already running using adf v2 triggers--azure

Tags: azure-data-factory

For ex: im scheduling a pipeline using schedule trigger/tumbling window trigger in adf v2 for **Frequency:min** which triggers for every minute.when first pipeline is still running i would like to put 2nd pipeline trigger in queue and start until 1st completed